# Add extra parameter to snmpwalk and receive at the agent side?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I am trying to set up an agent in the cloud and I want to distinguish my device based on the parameter passing in the snmpwalk.

```
snmpwalk -v3 -u user -l authNoPriv -A password <agent_IP> .1.3.6 "dev1"
```

If I put an observer function we are able to fetch some details like

```py
def requestObserver(snmpEngine, execpoint, variables, cbCtx):
    print('Execution point: %s' % execpoint)
    print('* securityModel: %s' % variables['securityModel'])
    print('* securityName: %s' % variables['securityName'])
    print('* contextEngineId: %s' % (variables['contextEngineId'] and variables['contextEngineId'].prettyPrint() or '<empty>',))
    print('* contextName: %s' % variables['contextName'].prettyPrint())
    print('* transportDomain: %s' % '.'.join([str(x) for x in variables['transportDomain']]))
    print('* transportAddress: %s' % '@'.join([str(x) for x in variables['transportAddress']]))
    print('* securityLevel: %s' % variables['securityLevel'])
    print('* PDU: %s' % variables['pdu'].prettyPrint())
```

but I don't know how to get this extra parameter in the agent side. If it is not possible, is there any other method exist for passing my device info to the agent?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "distinguish my device"? What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: I have set of devices with me and I store their details in some db and when some use snmpwalk I will send back the data

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: Each devices should have its own agent, and those agents should be assigned to dedicate IP addresses. That's the common setup for SNMP. The WALK operation does not take extra parameters, as it just walks through all the managed objects. If your setup/expectation is different and unique, edit your question to include more details please.